Code sign NUPKG file with a USB/Hardware token
I have an EV certificate from Sectigo to code sign, which is a hardware/USB token.
I need to code sign the app in the NUPKG file format, but the key is required through NuGet and the token I have has an undisclosed key and apparently, that's how it is for USB tokens.
Did anyone have a similar problem?
I'm looking for a way to sign NUPKG files, making it work with NuGet or Signtool.
I tried Signtool, but it's not reading the NUPKG file, only .EXE. I had unzipped the NUPKG file, signed with signtool, and then converted it back to NUPKG, but it didn't work.

You can try signing with Jsign (disclaimer: I'm the author of this project), the syntax looks like this:
jsign --storetype ETOKEN --storepass <password> package.nupkg

Note that the SafeNet Authentication Client must be installed first.

Tried this approach but I'm getting an error saying: jsign: Unsupported file: package.nupkg any idea why this is thrown?

.nupkg files will be supported in the soon to be released 7.0 version. You can download a preview of the next release from the artifacts section of the GitHub actions: https://github.com/ebourg/jsign/actions/runs/9797077297/artifacts/1668701812
